# Trocar imagens com Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Galera, estou tentando alterar uma imagem no click do botão e não estou conseguindo, o jquery me retorna esse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando fazer a troca utilizando o atributo data.
Meu código Jquery:

```js
$('#botao_troca_imagem').on('click',function() {
        jQuery().data('imagem').attr("src", "/public/default/images/marker.png");
        $("#botao_troca_imagem").remove();
});
```

Meu código HTML:

```html
<figure>

  <img data-imagem="troca_imagem" src="/public/default/images/mapa-google.jpg">

  <figcaption>

  <button id="botao_troca_imagem" role="button">Mostrar mapa</button>

  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este erro acontece pois o elemento que você está selecionando pra trocar não tem a propriedade "src" ou melhor, você não está selecionando de fato um elemento, no caso você tem que selecionar a tag img que você quer trocar:

```
$('#botao_troca_imagem').on('click',function() {
    $('img[data-imagem="troca_imagem"]').attr("src", "/public/default/images/marker.png");
    $("#botao_troca_imagem").remove();
});
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode trocar da seguinte maneira:

```
$('#botao_troca_imagem').on('click',function() {
 document.querySelector('.classe_imagem').src='/public/default/images/marker.png';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando se utiliza **data** deve-se utilizar o seletor do JQuery de maneira diferente, algo como: `$("[data-slide='meu-slides']");`, veja o exemplo no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8a4huxg/)
No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
$('#botao_troca_imagem').on('click',function() {
        $('img[data-imagem="troca_imagem"]').attr("src", "https://www.irdes.fr/imgs2017/images/about-imgs.jpg");
        $("#botao_troca_imagem").remove();
});
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você quer selecionar o elemento pelo atributo `data-imagem` que contenha o valor `troca_imagem`.

O método `.data()` retorna um valor e não um elemento, assim como o `.val()`. Para selecionar um elemento pelo valor de um atributo, você usa colchetes `[]` com o atributo e o valor:

```
$("[atributo='valor']")
```

No seu caso ficaria:

```
$('[data-imagem="troca_imagem"]')
```

Não precisa necessariamente colocar a tag `img` antes dos colchetes, assumindo que esse atributo e valor só exista em `img`.

Seu código ficaria melhor assim:

```
$('#botao_troca_imagem').on('click',function() {
   $('[data-imagem="troca_imagem"]').attr("src", "/public/default/images/marker.png");
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Como o elemento `#botao_troca_imagem` chamou o evento click e você quer removê-lo dentro do próprio evento, basta usar `$(this)` para referenciar o elemento.